# Windows 7- Unable to format disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I had a USB drive that I was previously using for a live linux install. It had several previous installs, and there were a lot of unused empty partitions on the disk as a result.

I used the `DISKPART CLEAN` command, and it went OK, except now, the disk is not visible Windows Explorer. Disk Management says it's all unallocated space, but I cannot format the disk, I just get the error `Unable to format disk` with no other information.

Comment: I also want to add that I am not that experienced with advanced Windows tools like this, I mainly use Linux and OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command:

1. `DiskPart`
2. `List Disk`
3. `Select Disk YOUR_DRIVE_NUMBER`

   > **WARNING:** Select the correct one which is your USB
4. `Clean`
5. `Create Partition Primary`
6. `Active`
7. `Format fs=FAT32 quick`
8. `Assign`

Now you should able to see your USB drive in Computer

Comment: PLEASE format your post correctly. I can't understand where one command ends and another starts.

Comment: Please try again, it was hard to format my text :$

Comment: DISKPART> select disk 1


Disk 1 is now the selected disk.


DISKPART> clean


DiskPart has encountered an error: Incorrect function.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> create partition primary

DiskPart succeeded in creating the specified partition.

DISKPART> active

DiskPart marked the current partition as active.

DISKPART> format fs=FAT32 quick

DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.
</code>

Comment: Sorry, Markdown isn't working. Anyway, when I tried to clean it it gave me 'Incorrect Function'.

Comment: can you also post `list partition` and `detail disk`?

Comment: btw, in your question you mentioned that you ran `DISKPART CLEAN command, and it went OK,`? but now it become `Incorrect function`?

Comment: Sure. I'll use pastebin from now on since the formatting is awful here. http://pastebin.com/pC0jJsgt

Comment: Oh. I appear to have missed that detail! It cleaned it fine the first time, but it did give me the error, yes.

Comment: What is the capacity of you usb?

Comment: I've done some exploration in the diskpart command, do I have to select the partition I want to format first (e.g SELECT PARTITION 1)?

Comment: The size of the usb is 7.5gb. (technically 7.632)

Comment: OK, it appears the only problem left now is assigning a drive letter. When I try to do that, it says 'cannot find the file specified'. Can't find any examples of this through Google.

Comment: It's been telling me to check the 'System' event log, but there are no new entries there.

Comment: I am just out for lunch now,  let see if any others answer later or i will get back in an hour :)

Comment: I FINALLY SOLVED IT! It seemed I just needed to re-mount the drive to get it to assign a proper letter, so the format could work! Thank you for all the help!